# c why realloc isn't working

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following code

```
void getPariceArray(Board board, treeNode *tn, Position *dst, int **prices, int *counter, int total)
{

    if (tn == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (tn->position[0] == dst[0][0] && tn->position[1] == dst[0][1])
    {
        prices = (int **)realloc(prices, sizeof(prices) *4);
        prices[*counter] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        printf("%d", sizeof(prices));
        *prices[*counter] = total;
        *counter = *counter + 1;
    }

    int x = tn->position[1] - '1';
    int y = tn->position[0] - 'A';

    int cellPrice = board[x][y] - '0';

    total += cellPrice;

    getPariceArray(board, tn->up, dst, prices, counter, total);
    getPariceArray(board, tn->down, dst, prices, counter, total);
    getPariceArray(board, tn->right, dst, prices, counter, total);
    getPariceArray(board, tn->left, dst, prices, counter, total);

}
```

prices is array of pointers and every step in recursion I'm casting realloc to increase the prices size.
I got many error bugs and I had a feeling it related to allocation, 
I printed the sizeof(prices) and I saw that it stayed 4 and not increase
Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

thanks in advance

P.S
Edit
I have another function that princt the **prices

```
void printPricesArray(int **arr, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("place:%d Price:%d\n", i, *arr[i]);
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting when `prices = realloc(prices, sizeof(prices) *4);`

[image: error bug]
 but when I'm changing the line to this `prices = realloc(prices, sizeof(prices) * 150);` everything goes well without errors because I know that in my example size isn't going passed 130, but I need dynamic increasing incase in different example size will be over 150.
[image: no errors bug]

Comment: `realloc(prices, sizeof(prices) *4);` never does anything different when the statement is run again. The memory allocation stays at that size:  4 array elements. Even with `sizeof(prices)`, the size of the pointer, not the size of the data it points to.

Comment: `I printed the sizeof(prices)`. `prices` is a pointer. `sizeof` a pointer will always returns the same. Also, you don't need to cast `malloc` or `realloc` in C.

Comment: is there any way to increase it?

Comment: `realloc` is working exactly as you're asking it to. Your *use* isn't working because [**`sizeof`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You need to explicitly keep track of the previous size and then use that to calculate a larger size on each `realloc`.

Comment: If the `*4` was supposed to be the data element size - that is where the `sizeof` was needed, not on the pointer. `sizeof(prices)` does not tell you how many array elements.

Comment: Rather than `prices  = realloc(prices, sizeof(prices) *4);`, I'd expect `realloc(prices, sizeof(*prices) *4);`   Note the extra *.  Unclear on the roll of `4` here.  Perhaps `*4` --> `* (*counter + 1)`.

Comment: topic edited with more info

Comment: @Brec One more bug seeker, never do `x = realloc(x, ...);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that during code writing and correcting (compiler) errors the code evolved into a wrong direction.

I feel that you actually do not want to handle an array of pointers to integers but a (dynamically growing) array of integer values (not pointers to them). Yet the circumstance, that the function has to rewrite the pointer to the array, which led to introduce one more '*' in the interface, took you into the dilemma, and statement `prices[*counter] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int))` indicates to me that this is the basic misunderstanding.

Let me explain what I mean it on the following short example.
Suppose that we want to have a function `dynamicPriceListAlloc`, which allocates an array of integers for `nrOfItems` integers.

Let's start with the caller, i.e. function main: Therein, as we want to have a dynamically allocated integer array, we will hold a variable of type `int *`, i.e. a pointer to this array. As we want to have the array allocated in a function, we have to pass a pointer to this pointer, because otherwise the function could not assign the newly allocated memory address to this pointer. Hence, `dynamicPriceListAlloc` must take a pointer to a pointer to ints, i.e. `int **`.

But - now the misleading thing - the intent of dynamicPriceListAlloc is not to allocate a pointer with *10 pointers* to ints, but to allocate an array of *10 integers* and assigning this memory block to the pointer passed (by reference) as argument:

```
int main(){

    int *priceList;
    dynamicPriceListAlloc(&priceList, 10);

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf("%d\n", priceList[i]);
}

void dynamicPriceListAlloc(int **prices, int nrOfItems) {
    *prices = (int*)malloc(nrOfItems * sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<nrOfItems; i++)
        // *prices[i] = i;  // Wrong: takes prices[i] and then dereferences it
        (*prices)[i] = i; // OK: derefernces prices (yielding a pointer an int-array) and then setting the i'th element
}
```

I suppose that you missed to correct the dereference-precedence thing in `*prices[i] = i`, and instead of correcting this to `(*prices)[i] = i`, you "solved" the problem by actually allocating storage for the pointer you dereference. And that's what I meant with "the code evolved in the wrong direction".

If I am right with this assumption, then your code would change as follows:

```
void getPariceArray(Board board, treeNode *tn, Position *dst, int **prices, int *counter, int total)
{
    if (tn == NULL)
        return;
    if (tn->position[0] == dst[0][0] && tn->position[1] == dst[0][1])
    {
        size_t sizeOfPrices = (*counter) * sizeof(int);
        *prices = (int*)realloc(*prices, sizeOfPrices);
        printf("size of prices: %ld", sizeOfPrices);
        (*prices)[*counter] = total;
        *counter = *counter + 1;
    }

    int x = tn->position[1] - '1';
    int y = tn->position[0] - 'A';

    int cellPrice = board[x][y] - '0';

    total += cellPrice;

    getPariceArray(board, tn->up, dst, prices, counter, total);
    getPariceArray(board, tn->down, dst, prices, counter, total);
    getPariceArray(board, tn->right, dst, prices, counter, total);
    getPariceArray(board, tn->left, dst, prices, counter, total);
}
```

And `printPricesArray` would be adapted as follows:

```
void printPricesArray(int *arr, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("place:%d Price:%d\n", i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `int **prices` wasn't my decision, but my school 1, its a school project and they gave me the function definision. but I agree, int array was much easier.

Comment: well, after second reading, I tried it, and it actually works